# Free online SMPP server

Tags: java, sms, smpp, smslib, jsmpp

I want to send and receive sms using jsmpp (or maybe smslib). I can send sms and get delivery report for my sms. But I cannot receive sms from SMSC. I downloaded Java SMPP Client application for receiving sms, but it didn't help. I want to test this software with online smpp server, if it receives sms from online server I will know that there is problem in provider, which gives me smpp gateway. Thanks..

Comment: http://smppex.rubybox.ru/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an online server you can use. However you can test your application locally by installing SMC simulator Here is a free [one](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html).

Comment: thanks for help! I downloaded, started server and connected with smpp client. But how can I send sms to smsc, for receiving in smpp client? I used source address, destination address in my application.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me! there is no problem with my software)

Comment: The tool is no longer available. Is there any other available tool?